# Configure Kubernetes API server to connect to a separate TLS secured etcd cluster with each member having it's own unique public certificate

Tags: linux, certificate, kubernetes

I am following Kubernetes the Hard Way without using Google cloud, and instead using container linux and a separate etcd cluster (one that doesn't exist on the control plane's controller nodes where the API server lives).

The environment looks like this:

`etcd01`, `etcd02`, `etcd03`

`controller01`, `controller02`, `controller03`

`worker01`, `worker02`, `worker03`

Every etcd member has their own unique public cert named `etcd{01,02,03}.lab.com.crt` with their own unique Subject Alternative Names and Common Name, and the controller-host's API servers have one cert on each machine which they all share (`api-server.crt`).

When following Kubernetes the Hard Way for the "Provisioning a CA and Generating TLS Certificates" section under "[The Kubernetes API Server Certificate](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#the-kubernetes-api-server-certificate)", he creates the following certificates:

```
kubernetes-key.pem
kubernetes.pem
```

In "[Configure the etcd Server](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/07-bootstrapping-etcd.md#configure-the-etcd-server)", he uses these two certs in the configuration with the intention of hosting the etcd instances on the controllers themselves.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \\
  --name ${ETCD_NAME} \\
  --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \\
  --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \\
  --peer-key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \\
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \\
  --peer-client-cert-auth \\
  --client-cert-auth \\
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://${INTERNAL_IP}:2380 \\
  --listen-peer-urls https://${INTERNAL_IP}:2380 \\
  --listen-client-urls https://${INTERNAL_IP}:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379 \\
  --advertise-client-urls https://${INTERNAL_IP}:2379 \\
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-0 \\
  --initial-cluster controller-0=https://10.240.0.10:2380,controller-1=https://10.240.0.11:2380,controller-2=https://10.240.0.12:2380 \\
  --initial-cluster-state new \\
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
```

Here is the configuration he uses in "[Configure the Kubernetes API Server](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md#configure-the-kubernetes-api-server)" for the API server, using the same certs as mentioned before:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver \\
  --advertise-address=${INTERNAL_IP} \\
  --allow-privileged=true \\
  --apiserver-count=3 \\
  --audit-log-maxage=30 \\
  --audit-log-maxbackup=3 \\
  --audit-log-maxsize=100 \\
  --audit-log-path=/var/log/audit.log \\
  --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC \\
  --bind-address=0.0.0.0 \\
  --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --enable-admission-plugins=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,NodeRestriction,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota \\
  --enable-swagger-ui=true \\
  --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --etcd-servers=https://10.240.0.10:2379,https://10.240.0.11:2379,https://10.240.0.12:2379 \\
  --event-ttl=1h \\
  --experimental-encryption-provider-config=/var/lib/kubernetes/encryption-config.yaml \\
  --kubelet-certificate-authority=/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem \\
  --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --kubelet-https=true \\
  --runtime-config=api/all \\
  --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/service-account.pem \\
  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.32.0.0/24 \\
  --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 \\
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \\
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \\
  --v=2
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
```

When looking up the documentation for the [Kubernetes API server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) regarding the configuration option `--etcd-certfile`, it states:

"`string: SSL certification file used to secure etcd communication.`"

This is great if you have the same cert for every etcd member, but how can I make this work when each etcd member has their own certificate file with different names, including unique Subject Alternative Names and Common Name?